# Xcode setting value to NSColorWell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

im facing this problem right now i need to set value for `NSColorWell`.I have like 3 sample codes where `NSColorWell` is bind to `Object Controller` when i right click on it it shows `selection.color -> Value colorwell` in `referencing bindings`, what is `selection.color` and how it's created ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selection` is [`[NSObjectController selection]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSObjectController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObjectController/selection) ([discussion](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/CntrlSelection.html)) and `color` will be a property within whatever object is currently selected within the object controller.  You should be able to view the object that's bound to the object controller from within Interface Builder.

Comment: thank you very much, i found everything i need in your posted link.